# Does a bar have to be filled up before the item is considered upgraded? Or do partially filled bars also count as an upgrade?

Tags: death-rally-2012

Does a bar have to be filled up before the item is considered upgraded? Or do partially filled bars also count as an upgrade?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only completed filled up bars are Bar counted as upgraded. Partially filled up bars are just to show progression.